# Telescoping series: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞}[\tan^{-1}(2n+1)-\tan^{-1}(2n-1)]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, summation, telescopic-series

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3998884/a-problem-on-inverse-trigonometric-function) question that was asked today the OP wrote that
$$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞}[\arctan(2n+1)-\arctan(2n-1)]&=\arctan\infty-\arctan 1\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\\&=\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}$$

I don't really understand why there is a $\arctan\infty$ term. Surely every single term other than $-\arctan 1$ has been cancelled out? Now I know that I am wrong, as obviously the value of the summation cannot be negative, but I'm not sure where I am wrong.

I have thought of considering the similar finite series, $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k[\arctan(2n+1)-\arctan(2n-1)]=\arctan(2k+1)-\arctan1$$
and letting $k\to\infty$, so that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^k[\arctan(2n+1)-\arctan(2n-1)]=\arctan\infty-\arctan1$$ as required, but I still can't see why all the terms other than $-\arctan1$ don't cancel out, as the upper limit actually *is* $\infty$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^k[\arctan(2n+1)-\arctan(2n-1)]=$$
$$(\arctan(3)-\arctan(1))+(\arctan(5)-\arctan(3))+(\arctan(7)-\arctan(5))+\cdots+(\arctan(2k-1)-\arctan(2k-3))+(\arctan(2k+1)-\arctan(2k-1)) =$$ $$=\arctan(2k+1)-\arctan(1)$$

Comment: @TitoEliatron right. But our series is infinite.

Comment: This is the $k$-th  PARTIAL SUM.  The series converges iff the sequence of partial sums converges. And in this particular case, the sequence $S_k$ of partial sums converges to $\arctan(+\infty)-\arctan(1)=\pi/2-\pi/4=\pi/4$.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Why does finiteness matter? How is it any different from taking the limit $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @AnkitSaha with the infinite series group the terms differently: $$-\arctan 1+(\arctan 3-\arctan3)+(\arctan5-\arctan5)+\cdots+(\arctan(k)-\arctan(k))+\cdots$$-

Comment: But there aren't enough terms to group every term apart from $-\tan^{-1}1$. Say, there are $2n$ terms with $n \to \infty$. Leaving $-\tan^{-1}1$ aside, there are $2n-1$ terms left, which is an odd number. So you won't be able to pair every number and $\tan^{-1} \infty $ will be left out.

Comment: No, but there are surely an even number of terms in the summation.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/finding-tan-t-if-t-sum-tan-11-2t2?rq=1

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - Tito Eliatron gave you the correct formula for the partial sum of the series you asked about. Your "different grouping" is not allowed because the original series has the grouping Tito Eliatron used built into it. Your counter-example is a different series. Both series can be considered rearrangements of the alternating series with one arctan per term. But that series is not absolutely convergent, so different rearrangements of it can converge to different values. Your counter-example does not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few intermediate steps might be helpful.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{\left[\arctan(2n+1)-\arctan(2n-1)\right]}\\
> &=\lim_{N\to\infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\arctan(2n+1)-\arctan(2n-1)\right]}\\
> &=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\arctan(2N+1)-\arctan(1)\right]\tag{1}\\
> &=\lim_{N\to\infty}\arctan(2N+1)-\lim_{N\to\infty}\arctan(1)\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\pi}{4}}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply telescoping.
- In (2) we use $\lim_{N\to\infty}\arctan(N)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty} a=a$.